# harddisk not readable and not booting

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have installed ubuntu 10.10 on my HP Pavilion dv-7 4285dx laptop.
When I try to perform a smart test on the hard drive, it informs me of several bad sectors and shows message like this:

> Current Pending Sector Count
>   Number of Sectors Waiting to be Remapped.If the sector waiting to be remapped is subsequently 
>   written or read successfully, this value should be decreased and the sector remapped. Read Errors on the Sector will not remap the Sector, it will only be remapped on a failed write
>   attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Your hard drive is having significant hardware issues. It is probably time to get a new drive, even if the sectors are remapped.